# Ошибка при развёртке Базы данных - Database file version 11.2.0.4.0 incompatible with ORACLE version 10.2.0.0.0

Tags: oracle, cmd, oracle11g

Переношу базу данных `Oracle` с одного компьютера на другой.База данных была создана в `Oracle 11`.
Переустановил новые `controlfile`,чтобы дальше работать с базой но возникла следующая ошибка(см.на рисунках ниже).
Перед этим прилагаю список команда через `CMD(выполнено то имени администратора)`

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>C:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN>set ORACLE_SID=LOVDTNAL
C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\BIN>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production on Tue Oct 11 17:43:23 2022  
Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

SQL> conn sys/sys as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> startup nomount pfile=D:\oracle\admin\LOVDTNAL\pfile\init.ora

SQL> CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "LOVDTNAL" NORESETLOGS  NOARCHIVELOG
  2         MAXLOGFILES 16
  3         MAXLOGMEMBERS 3
  4         MAXDATAFILES 100
  5         MAXINSTANCES 8
  6         MAXLOGHISTORY 584
  7     LOGFILE
  8          GROUP 1 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO01.LOG'  SIZE 50M,
  9          GROUP 2 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO02.LOG'  SIZE 50M,
 10          GROUP 3 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\REDO03.LOG'  SIZE 50M
 11    -- STANDBY LOGFILE
 12     DATAFILE
 13       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSTEM01.DBF',
 14       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\UNDOTBS01.DBF',
 15       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSAUX01.DBF',
 16       'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\LOVDTNAL\USERS01.DBF',
 17       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\MAIN.DBF',
 18       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\INDEX.DBF',
 19       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\LOB.DBF',
 20       'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\XDB.DBF'
 21     CHARACTER SET CL8MSWIN1251;
CREATE CONTROLFILE REUSE DATABASE "LOVDTNAL" NORESETLOGS  NOARCHIVELOG
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01503: CREATE CONTROLFILE failed
ORA-01130: database file version 11.2.0.4.0 incompatible with ORACLE version
10.2.0.0.0
ORA-01110: data file 1: 'D:\oracle\oradata\LOVDTNAL\SYSTEM01.DBF'
```

P.S.
На данном компьютере стоят несколько десятков баз, которые были созданы в Oracle 10.2.0 и в Oracle 11.2.0.
Аналогичные действия,описанные выше я делал и через Oracle 11.2.0.
К сожалению в обоих случаях выходит ошибка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]     Database file version 11.2.0.4.0 incompatible with ORACLE version 10.2.0.0.0

**UPDATE**

Сейчас заметил,что при выходе из sqlplus у меня показывается версия 10.2.0 при то,что я входил через `product/11.2.0/.../BIN/sqlplus.exe`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос,а как сделать мне так,чтобы после `conn sys/sys` я заходил в `sqlplus` от `11.2.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно выставить правильно переменные окружения, чтобы они указывали на правильный `ORACLE_HOME` и `ORACLE_SID`, и чтобы в переменной `PATH` был каталог `BIN` из того же `ORACLE_HOME`. Для этого перед запуском `sqlplus.exe` выполните сначала в том же `CMD.EXE` окне:

```
set ORACLE_HOME=C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\db_1
set ORACLE_SID=LOVDTNAL
```

Только конечно укажите правильный путь, я выше привёл просто пример.

С переменной `PATH` чуть больше телодвижений. Если вывести текущее значение через `set PATH`, скорее всего в выводе будет уже путь к какому-то каталогу `BIN` в `ORACLE_HOME` (к последнему инсталлированому). В выводе может быть и несколько каталогов `BIN`, в разных `ORACLE_HOME`, инсталлятор OUI иногда обновляет переменную окружения `PATH`, а иногда дописывает новый `ORACLE_HOME\BIN` после каждой новой инсталляции. Я честно говоря не знаю логику, когда какое действие OUI выполняет. В общем, нужно вывести текущее значение `PATH`, убрать все ненужные значения:

```
set PATH
<тут будет вывод текущего значения PATH с каким-то ORACLE_HOME\BIN в конце - копируем все без ORACLE_HOME\BIN>

set PATH=тут существующие значения до первого ORACLE_HOME
set PATH=%PATH%;%ORACLE_HOME%\BIN
```

Т.е. мы тут выводим текущее значение `PATH`, очищаем его от неправильного `ORACLE_HOME\BIN`, и дальше формируем правильный `PATH`, с нужным каталогом `BIN`.

Вот и все.